# how to hold the current page after second request

Tags: struts2

Hi friends.

I am working with Struts Hibernate and Spring in my application. I am retrieving data from bd and in the same page I had another hyperlink when I click that one it should retrieve data from another table and should display that under the previous table but the problem I am facing is when I click the another hyperlink the control is going new page and is not showing previous data. So please help me to resolve this problem!
Thanks in advance.

Sunny

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on the [Struts2 AJAX](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html) framework.  By doing an AJAX request you can load this data without requiring an entire page refresh.